# how to call another intent from any intent have followup intent in dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have multiple intents on root level in dialogflow : 
let say I have intent called: anchor and theme, in that theme intent, I have followup intent called videos so when user invokes the theme intent I am showing list of anchor related to that theme and suggestion chips to invoke videos followup intent whenever user tries to click in anchor item and it invoking that followup intent and not going on anchor intent

help me to configure those dialog flow intents

I had given some training phrases with that entity of anchor names for anchor intent

I want to invoke that anchor intent whenever the user clicks on the list and invokes vides followup intent when a user clicks on suggestion chips of videos.

Comment: Can you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your anchor intent and the fallback are using samples that are too similar. I tried this scenario and even with the training in Dialogflow I am unable to not trigger the the fallback on a chip called Anchor. The fallback intent creates a context, this context will always prefer intents which belong to this context over anything else.

So if you use words that are too similar in both the anchor intent and in the fallback, you will always end up in the fallback. What you can try is finding a word that isn't the same as the word that you use for you fallback. Kind of like this.

[image]

[image]

The fallback is trained to trigger to anchor and the anchor intent is triggered to Other word. You could also train them the other way around so that anchor will trigger to anchor and fallback to other word.